# How to make iframe body not obscured?

Tags: html, css, iframe

[image]

I am having a problem that has wasted a lot of time already, I have to ask people for help, Please see the image and the code for clarity

Code page index (parent):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="divParentIframeChatbox" style="
            width:700px;
            height:5px;
            position:fixed;
            right:400px;
            bottom:5px;
            background-color:rebeccapurple;
        ">
        <iframe id="iframeChatBox"
                src="http://localhost:53398/chatbox.html"
                style="
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
        "></iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code page iframe(child):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: red;">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: For a number of reasons i can't set increase height of divParentIframeChatbox ,
Thanks so much**

Comment: Check on your browser console to see if there is any error related to the iframe. http websites gets often blocked especially when using Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @silviagreen you mean "X-Frame-Option: SAME ORIGIN" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the z-index of divParentIframeChatbox to some higher value say:

```css
.divParentIframeChatbox{
z-index: 2147483000;
}
```